# Need help in python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a list of links below, what i need is regex to get the word `super-hydration-duo-kit` and `face-palette` and `deluxe-tan-remover`

```
https://www.beautybay.com/p/coco-and-eve/super-hydration-duo-kit/
https://www.beautybay.com/p/beauty-bay/face-palette/first-light/
https://www.beautybay.com/p/loving-tan/deluxe-tan-remover/200/
```

I have tried this regex but not getting the desired result

```
.*(?<=p/)([\w-]+)
```

The output i am getting is `coco-and-eve` which is not what i want.

I don't need the word that is immediately after `p/`, i need the next word after that word i.e `deluxe-tan-remover` in the 3rd link

Comment: @s3dev That will extract the path, but I don't think it will help with selecting a specific directory in the path.

Comment: Do you have to use a regexp? Use `split('/')` to split it into a list. Find the index of `p` and then get the 2nd element after that.

Comment: If you need a regexp: `/p/[^/]*/([^/]*)`. You were missing the part that skips over the directory after `/p/`.

Comment: Please write a descriptive title, say, "How can I get the URL path component two down from a known part?", though that's kind of dense. For tips on how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: I think `url.split("/")[5]` should give you want you want.